# Read private key in .KEY format with PKI.JS for CMS EnvelopedData

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, cryptography, pki

I'm trying to modify this example of CMS EnvelopedData:

https://pkijs.org/examples/CMSEnvelopedExample.html

to read a local KEY + CERT + PASSWORD,

so far, I was able to read the CERT with the HTML5's "File API" (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

but once I got the envelop and I try to open it, it throws me this error:

```
DataError: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements
```

In the documentation (https://github.com/GlobalSign/PKI.js/wiki/Working-with-CMS-EnvelopedData), it says that the private key hast to be in PKCS8 format, but I don't know how to convert it or how to generate it from the KEY,

> recipientPrivateKey - ArrayBuffer - The encoded PKCS#8 structure for
>   recipient's private key. This field is mandatory for recipient's types
>   KeyTransRecipientInfo and KeyAgreeRecipientInfo;

also the PASSWORD of the KEY is never used, and even if I pass it in the **preDefinedData**, it doesn't work

> preDefinedData - ArrayBuffer - Early used pre-shared data (pre-shared
>   "key encryption key" or password).

:( what am i missing? or how should I be passing the private key?

Comment: Hello Alfredo, do you have any update? Thanks

Comment: @IgnacioOcampo Nop, the guy from PKIJS didn't help [link](https://github.com/GlobalSign/PKI.js/issues/53)

Comment: I have solved the problem.